# Enable registry editing on remote machine

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Trying to edit remote machine registry wit Registry editor. I do this by pressing `File->Connect Network Registry` and entering remote IP. Got error:

```
Error Connecting Network Registry
Unable to connect to 192.168.1.172.  Make sure you have permission to administer this computer.
```

How to set remote administration permission?

UPD

I got login window after connecting to network registry. I have entered remote machine user by entering data in remote_machine\remote_username  format. Remote machine user belongs to Administrator group. But I still have no full access to registry.

Comment: Are you the administrator of the other machine?  Have you tried SysInternals PS Exec to make the change on the other machine?

Answer (score 0):

*Connect Network Registry* requires typing the **name** of the computer you want to
remotely access.

This is the host-name of the other computer, not its IP address.

If you would like to search for the exact name, click the "Advanced..."
button, then "Find now" and wait.
When the name-list is displayed, double-click
the remote computer to bring it into the box, then click OK.

You need administrator privileges on the remote computer to have full access.
Without it, you will only see HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_USERS
and may get "Access is denied"  on some folders.

For more information, see the article
[How to Connect to a Remote Registry](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-registry-2625147).

Comment: Looks like IP address is ok, I got remote registry, but only HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_USERS. How to get administrator privileges on remote computer? Both machines runes on the same workgroup.

Comment: Strange, IP address didn't work for me, only the name. When you're prompted to enter the username and password on the remote computer, this should be an administrator account for full permissions. The missing three registry hives can be drived from various subkeys within the two hives that you do see. In the article I linked to, see the section "Why Am I Seeing an “Access Denied” Message?" and click on the their names for more information.

Comment: I got login window after connecting to network registry. I have entered remote machine user by entering data in remote_machine\remote_username  format. Remote machine user belongs to Administrator group. But I still have no full access to registry.

Comment: The missing three registry hives can be derived from various subkeys within the two hives that you do see.

Answer (score 0):

The `Remote Registry` service must be running on BOTH sides of the Remote Registry connection. So first, turn it on for your admin workstation.

You can verify if `Remote Registry` service is running on a remote machine with the `sc.exe` command. In these examples, change `ComputerName` to match the device you want to remotely manage.

```
sc \\ComputerName  query RemoteRegistry
```

NOTE: If you get an `The RPC server is unavailable.` error then you will need a remote shell session to run commands against the computer. `PsExec` is a popular remote shell for Windows.

1. Ensure that the `Remote Registry` service is enabled:

```
sc \\ComputerName config RemoteRegistry start=auto
```

2. Ensure that the `Remote Registry` service is started:

```
sc start RemoteRegistry
```

3. Try the connection again.

There are other network reasons why your connection might fail. The port needs to be open in the OS firewall of the remote machine. There needs to be a clear, local, network path for that connection to traverse to the destination port.